# Automatically Uploading files every night + php

Tags: php, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I have a php program to create and upload xml files. Uploading files on button click is consuming around one hour.
My xml data contains information about assigned duties for the coming week and is updated every Friday.
I heard about batch files, task scheduler etc. which are absolutely new terms for me. As far as I understood, it is possible to upload xml data for each day the previous night. But, I don't have any idea how to achieve it.

1. how can I use a batch file to change the date used in the sql query  for xml file making.
   (select * from table between "today 12am" to "tomorrow 11pm")?
   Can I can make tomorrow's xml file and upload it today midnight ?
2. How can I execute this program every day automatically?

Excuse me if there is any mistake.As I said before, I don't know much about these. My questions are only based on the Google research for the last 3-4 hours.

Comment: "How can I execute this program every day automatically"...as you already said yourself, you can do it using Windows Scheduled Tasks (or Cron, if you use linux/Mac). It's easy to google how to set up a scheduled task. It's unclear where you're stuck with this part of the question. Have you tried something and failed?

Comment: "how can I use a batch file"...not sure why you'd need a batch file for this. Just use PHP to control which query is executed, based on the current date. The scheduled task can execute the PHP script directly, no need for batch files.

Comment: Thanks ADyson. Yeah, it is possible to change dates using php script itself.

Comment: Now, what I understood is, I have to keep the program to create and upload one day's XML file inside a php file. Then, make a batch file to run it. And, schedule the batch file execution every night using task scheduler. Isn't it the right procedure?

Comment: If you're only going to execute one PHP script each time, then you don't need the batch file. A batch file is only useful if you need to execute multiple operating system commands in sequence, without user intervention. So I think you can just schedule your PHP script directly.

Comment: OK. Thank you very much. I will try like that. So helpful !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work using Windows Task scheduler( [How to use Taskscheduler](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-automated-task-using-task-scheduler-windows-10) )and batch files.
Batch file(passDate.bat) Looks like this:

```
PATH=%PATH%;C:\xampp\php
CD MYFOLDERNAME
php Create_XML.php %date%
exit
```

and in the Create_XML.php I fetch the new date using

```
echo $new_date = $argv[1];
```